# os.open, os.seek, os.write Golang

Tags: golang

Только начинаю осваивать Golang, так что прошу прощения за может быть глупый вопрос.
Есть простая функция на python:

```
def write_block_to(datablock, block, fname):
    path = '/ida/'+fname
    fd = open(path, 'ab+')
    fd.seek(block,1)
    b = datablock
    fd.write(b)
    fd.close()
```

Как это просто реализовать на Go? Голову уже сломал.

```
func Write_Block_to(read_buf []byte, block int64, fname string){
path := "/ida/"+fname
f, e := os.OpenFile(path,  os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
if e != nil {
    panic(e)
}
defer f.Close()
_, err := f.Seek(block, 1)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
fmt.Println(string(read_buf))
if _, err := w.Write(read_buf); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

) тут тоже не до конца понял, все ли верно пишу?

Comment: Практика - критерий истины. Если код работает как ожидается, значит правильно. В чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: Код работает без ошибок, но в файл записываеися 0 байт, если я не буду использовать буфер и напишу _, err  = f.Write(read_buf)
 if err != nil {
  panic(err)
 } то все работает, но мне надо записать именно таким чанком, если байт в нем нет? то чтобы были zero byte до конца длины блока (65538)

Comment: Нужно было добавить `if err = w.Flush(); err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }` теперь все записалось